# Map with different data type, variable does not exist

Tags: apex

I am having trouble Saving data through Apex
I send to Apex a dict that have different Data type such as {"id": 12345, "field_name":44}

now what I would like to do is

1. send this data to Apex
2. Get the specific lead via the Id
3. update the fields

---

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void UW_SavedData(Map<String, Object> record){
    if(record != null){
        string currentId = record.id;
        Lead CurrentProp = [SELECT Id FROM Lead WHERE Id = :record.id];          
        }
    }
```

My apex look the following ..

my issue is that for :record.id I get the error Variable does not exist: id

Could you explain me what I am doing wrong ?

edited Code:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void UW_SavedData(Lead record){
    if(record != null){
        Id currentId = record.get('Id');
        Lead CurrentProp = [SELECT Id FROM Lead WHERE Id = :currentId];          
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a map, you'd have to write:

```
Id currentId = (Id)record.get('Id');
```

Note that this is case sensitive. You might want to just pass in a record directly:

```
public static void UW_SavedData(Lead record){
```

This saves you the trouble of using Maps in Apex.

Comment: thx you, I edited my code have a look , but now I get an error Illegal assignment from Object to Id on the line Id currentId = record.ger('Id')

Comment: Oh I got you, I do not use the Map thing .get

Comment: @Ben2pop Yes, there should have been a "cast" to tell the compiler the data type we expect.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike JavaScript, to get the value from a key value pair i.e., a map in Apex, you will have to use the `get` method. For example:

```
record.get('Id')
```